# Pandas calculate points per game when number of matches per team is NOT a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working with a dataset that looks like this:

[image: dataset]

I want to analyze the most effective teams from this dataset so I have decided to calculate points based on their results and then calculate points per game. For reference, a win is 3 points, a draw is 1 point and a loss is 0 points. So to calculate points I decided to add two new columns that say how many points the home team and away team got. I did this by:

```
since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] > 0, 'points_home_team'] = 3
since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] == 0, 'points_home_team'] = 1
since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] < 0, 'points_home_team'] = 0

since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] > 0, 'points_away_team'] = 0
since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] == 0, 'points_away_team'] = 1
since_2018.loc[since_2018['home_score'] - since_2018['away_score'] < 0, 'points_away_team'] = 3
```

This is giving me a `SettingWithCopyWarning` but the code seems to be working fine as this is what the dataset looks like after:
[image: dataset with points]

To get total points I did this:

```
home_points = (since_2018.groupby(['home_team'])['points_home_team'].sum() + since_2018.groupby(['away_team'])['points_away_team'].sum())
home_points.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Now I want to calculate points per game for each team in order to see which teams have been the most effective and I think I managed to get a number for games played by each team through this code:

```
matches = since_2018.groupby("home_team").count() + since_2018.groupby('away_team').count()
```

So now from there I am stuck as to how to actually use those number of games and points to get points per game. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

For reference, here is a text version of the dataset:

```
    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tournament  city    country neutral total_goals points_home_team    points_away_team
date                                            
2018-01-02  Iraq    United Arab Emirates    0   0   Gulf Cup    Kuwait City Kuwait  True    0   1.0 1.0
2018-01-02  Oman    Bahrain 1   0   Gulf Cup    Kuwait City Kuwait  True    1   3.0 0.0
2018-01-05  Oman    United Arab Emirates    0   0   Gulf Cup    Kuwait City Kuwait  True    0   1.0 1.0
2018-01-07  Estonia Sweden  1   1   Friendly    Abu Dhabi   United Arab Emirates    True    2   1.0 1.0
2018-01-11  Denmark Sweden  0   1   Friendly    Abu Dhabi   United Arab Emirates    True    1   0.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set the home/away scores:

`net_goals = since_2018.home_score - since_2018.away_score`

`home_points = [3 if ng>0 else 1 if ng==0 else 0 for ng in net_goals]`

And the inverse for `away_points`

Now change

`matches = since_2018.groupby("home_team").count() + since_2018.groupby('away_team').count()`

To
... `.groupby('home_team').home_points.agg(['sum', 'count'])` ...

and you are almost done

Comment: hi thanks for the response. When trying out the groupby edit you recommended, I get this following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'home_points'`

Comment: Yes, you need to set home and away points as a column in your df

Comment: yes! Totally missed that, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a dedicated total points data frame and add a column for the number of matches to it. Combine the home and away teams to calculate the points per game.

```
df_h = pd.concat([since_2018.groupby(['home_team'])['points_home_team'].sum(),since_2018.groupby("home_team").size()], keys='home_team', axis=1)
df_h.columns = ['points', 'matches']
df_a = pd.concat([since_2018.groupby(['away_team'])['points_away_team'].sum(),since_2018.groupby('away_team').size()], keys='away_team', axis=1)
df_a.columns = ['points', 'matches']
result = pd.concat([df_h, df_a], axis=0)
result['rate'] = result['points'] / result['matches']
result

points  matches rate
Denmark 0.0 1   0.0
Estonia 1.0 1   1.0
Iraq    1.0 1   1.0
Oman    4.0 2   2.0
Bahrain 0.0 1   0.0
Sweden  4.0 2   2.0
United Arab Emirates    2.0 2   1.0
```